# Python: retrieve active window position and size (OSX and Windows)

Tags: python

Looking for a way to figure out the size and position of an active window.

I did search and found solutions that works only on OSX or Windows, but I was not able to find anything that I can use on both platforms, directly from Python.

Do I have to make 2 different implementations for this, or there is a simple way to get window size and position in python, implementing it once?

Comment: can you make a function that will try the Windows solution and if it doesn't work it will try OSX and just use that function in your code ?

Comment: Yes, that was my "fallback" solution if I can't find a common way to accomplish it

Comment: I see, well I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help. I wouldn't feel that bad about using that 'fallback' if I where you because ill bet if any solution already exists it does the exact same thing.

Comment: I think you will need to go with your fallback solution since any third party package you use to do it will most likely use two different methods for OSX and Windows itself (if it supports it). So I guess you're just delaying the inevitable.

Comment: Well, let's take as example screenshots; you can use one single Python library on both OSX and Windows; and that one use PIL as background, implementing multiple WM in the background. Excluding that a solution exist, would be hasty...Someone else may already have the whole implementation of the multi-platform part done; which means that I do not have to write it again and re-invent the wheel